# Subset data A with data B - but keep information of relevant column of B

Tags: r, subset

I have two dataframes, say A and B, and want to subset A using column information (matching). So far so good - this is something I already know. (I know about match, which and %in%). What I need is a little bit more complicated and I just cant wrap my mind around this. I want to keep track of information of a column/columns of B.

An example:

```
words <- c("Hello","Experts","Please","Help","Me","Out","With","This","Problem","!")
letterV <- toupper(letters[1:20])
numbersV <- 1:20
combV <- paste("Test_",letters[1:10],sep = "")
rainbowV <- rainbow(20)

testDF.A <- as.data.frame(cbind(letterV,cbind(numbersV,cbind(combV,rainbowV))),stringsAsFactors = F)
testDF.B <- as.data.frame(cbind(numbersV[1:10],cbind(letterV[1:10],cbind(combV,words))),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

testDF_A:

```
    letterV numbersV    combV   rainbowV
1   A       1           Test_a  #FF0000FF
2   B       2           Test_b  #FF4D00FF
3   C       3           Test_c  #FF9900FF
4   D       4           Test_d  #FFE500FF
5   E       5           Test_e  #CCFF00FF
6   F       6           Test_f  #80FF00FF
7   G       7           Test_g  #33FF00FF
8   H       8           Test_h  #00FF19FF
9   I       9           Test_i  #00FF66FF
10  J       10          Test_j  #00FFB2FF
11  K       11          Test_a  #00FFFFFF
12  L       12          Test_b  #00B3FFFF
13  M       13          Test_c  #0066FFFF
14  N       14          Test_d  #001AFFFF
15  O       15          Test_e  #3300FFFF
16  P       16          Test_f  #7F00FFFF
17  Q       17          Test_g  #CC00FFFF
18  R       18          Test_h  #FF00E6FF
19  S       19          Test_i  #FF0099FF
20  T       20          Test_j  #FF004DFF
```

testDF_B:

```
    V1  V2  combV   words
1   1   A   Test_a  Hello
2   2   B   Test_b  Experts
3   3   C   Test_c  Please
4   4   D   Test_d  Help
5   5   E   Test_e  Me
6   6   F   Test_f  Out
7   7   G   Test_g  With
8   8   H   Test_h  This
9   9   I   Test_i  Problem
10  10  J   Test_j  !
```

Let's say I want to compare/match A[,3] and B[,3] but keep info B[,4]
expected result:

```
    keptCol letterV numbersV    combV   rainbowV
1   Hello   A       1           Test_a  #FF0000FF
2   Experts B       2           Test_b  #FF4D00FF
3   Please  C       3           Test_c  #FF9900FF
4   Help    D       4           Test_d  #FFE500FF
5   Me      E       5           Test_e  #CCFF00FF
6   Out     F       6           Test_f  #80FF00FF
7   With    G       7           Test_g  #33FF00FF
8   This    H       8           Test_h  #00FF19FF
9   Problem I       9           Test_i  #00FF66FF
10  !       J       10          Test_j  #00FFB2FF
11  Hello   K       11          Test_a  #00FFFFFF
12  Experts L       12          Test_b  #00B3FFFF
13  Please  M       13          Test_c  #0066FFFF
14  Help    N       14          Test_d  #001AFFFF
15  Me      O       15          Test_e  #3300FFFF
16  Out     P       16          Test_f  #7F00FFFF
17  With    Q       17          Test_g  #CC00FFFF
18  This    R       18          Test_h  #FF00E6FF
19  Problem S       19          Test_i  #FF0099FF
20  !       T       20          Test_j  #FF004DFF
```

To make it even harder to think about - i actually need multi hits to be covered too:

Let's say I want to compare/match A[,2] and B[,1] but keep info of B[,2]

```
small.a <- as.data.frame(cbind(letters[1:6],cbind(c("Test_a","Test_a","Test_b","Test_a","Test_c","Test_z"),c("a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1"))),stringsAsFactors = F)
small.b <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("Test_a","Test_b","Test_d","Test_e","Test_b"),c("Thank","You","Very","Much","!")),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

small.a

```
    V1  V2      V3
1   a   Test_a  a1
2   b   Test_a  b1
3   c   Test_b  c1
4   d   Test_a  d1
5   e   Test_c  e1
6   f   Test_z  f1
```

small.b

```
    V1      V2
1   Test_a  Thank
2   Test_b  You
3   Test_d  Very
4   Test_e  Much
5   Test_b  !
```

expected result:

```
    keptCol V1  V2          V3
1   Thank   a   Test_a      a1
2   Thank   b   Test_a      b1
3   You     c   Test_b      c1
4   !       c   Test_b      c1
5   Thank   d   Test_a      d1
```

Another issue might be if i wanted to keep information of multiple columns...

I hope I provided enough information for you to understand the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(small.a, small.b, by=c('V2'='V1'))
```

Or using `merge`

```
merge(small.a, small.b, by.x='V2', by.y='V1')
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem concerning usage of variable names as 'by' arguments: 'nameA = names(dFrameA)[colNum]'  Something like this is not accepted here - do you by chance know a workaround?

Comment: May be you have to change the column name before. `names(yourdataset)[number] <- names(dFrameA)[colNum]`